# Callback of trash button not called

Tags: ios, button, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am developing my first application with Titanium Alloy. For iOS i use the native iOS trash button, using `systemButton="TRASH"`. For that button i also have an `onClick` handler, `onClick="deleteReckon"`. However, the `deleteReckon` method is not called upon clicking the trash button.

This is the "reckonDetails.xml" view for iOS (hence, included in an "ios" directory in the "views" directory) :

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">

        <!-- Make a toolbar for delete and info buttons -->
        <Toolbar platform="ios" bottom="0" borderTop="true" borderBottom="false">

                <!-- The Items tag sets the Toolbar.items property. -->
                <Items>
                    <Button id="info" systemButton="INFO_LIGHT" />
                    <FlexSpace/>
                    <Button id="del" onClick="deleteReckon" systemButton="TRASH" />
                </Items>

       </Toolbar>

        <!-- We will display all reckon detail, date, total, ... -->
     <View layout='vertical'>
          <Label id="dateLabel"></Label>
          <!-- ... OTHER LABELS ... -->
     </View>
   </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And this is the "reckonDetails.js" controller :

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

// Fill in all labels of this view
$.dateLabel.text = "Date: " + args.date || 'Unknown Date';
// ...

function deleteReckon() {
    console.log("deleteReckon called"); // Is never displayed

    // Delete the selected reckon (this element of the collection)
    var selectedReckon = args.selected_reckon;
    selectedReckon.destroy(); 

    // Go back to the index page
    var args = {};
    var indexView = Alloy.createController("index", args).getView();
    indexView.open();
}
```

I put a `console.log(...);` statement in it to check if the function is called, but it is not..

And finally this is my "reckonDetails.tss" style (not sure if this is relevant for the problem?) :

```
".container[platform=ios]" : { 
   backgroundColor: 'white' 
},

"Label": {
    font: {
        fontSize: '20'
    },
    left: '10'
},

"#dateLabel": {
    font: {
        fontSize: '30'
    },
    left: '10'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested iOS system TRASH button on Titanium Alloy and Classic project and it's working just fine for me. Please have a look on my code below,

```
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'Window',
    backgroundColor: '#white'
});

var trash = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.TRASH,
});

flexSpace = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE
});

var toolbar = Titanium.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
    items:[trash, flexSpace],
    bottom:0,
    borderTop:true,
    borderBottom:false
}); 
win.add(toolbar);

trash.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("Treash called");
});

win.open();
```

Hope you can now find what you are looking for. For more details, please check the documentation from here at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.SystemButton-property-TRASH and http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.Toolbar.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. When i define the trash button using the "traditional" way as you do and add an event listener to it it works. I wonder why it does not work when i define the button in XML with an `onClick` attribute.